# Data tables for Meteor using aldeed:tabular

Tags: javascript, meteor, datatables

I am using loading data to data table from webservice. I have multiple records, now I want to add button which will show 4 rows or all rows. I am aware of option iDisplayLength, but I don't know how to access to that variable.

Here is how my data table initialization looks like:

```
Places = new Mongo.Collection("places");
TabularTables = {};
Meteor.isClient && Template.registerHelper('TabularTables', TabularTables);

TabularTables.Places = new Tabular.Table({
    name: "LocationsList",
    collection: Places,
    columns: [
        {data: "naziv", title: "Name"},
        // {data: "status", title: "Status"},
        // {data: "bencinska", title: "Station"},
        {data: "razdalja", title: "Distance (km)"},
        {data: "", title: "",
            tmpl: Meteor.isClient && Template.btn_favorite,
            tmplContext: function(rowData) {
                return {
                    item: rowData,
                    column: ""
                };
            }
        }
    ],
    // aLengthMenu: [[3, -1], [3, "Vsi"]],
    iDisplayLength: -1,
    order: [[ 1, "asc" ]],
    limit: 30,
    responsive: true,
    autoWidth: false
});
```

And here is my template:

```
<template name="table">
    {{> tabular table=TabularTables.Places class="table centered highlight compact" id="data_table"}}
</template>
```

If someone knows a good pattern to load table (now it shows no data available, when it's not loaded), please give me an advice. Is there a flag when data is loaded and when it's not yet?

EDIT:

I have deleted filters and showing items helpers from datatable, because I want to solve this with more elegant design.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things, first, it would probably be best if you mention the version of the library you are using when asking questions about any library. I'll assume you are using DataTables 1.10.x. But note, there was an API change with this version and if you are using v1.9 or earlier, this information may not apply.

Secondly, options are for initialization only. So you can't look to use `iDisplayLength` to solve this problem.

[Options](https://datatables.net/manual/options):

> DataTables' huge range of options can be used to customise the way
>   that it will present its interface, and the features available, to the
>   end user. This is done through its configuration options, which are
>   **set at initialisation time**.

That said, I can't write the code to try this, but I think you are going to need to use the `page.len()` [method](https://datatables.net/reference/api/page.len()).

Note, you can pass -1 to it to show all rows, otherwise, the parameter passed is the number of rows you want to show.

Answer (score 0):

```js
import Tabular from "meteor/aldeed:tabular";
var Users = new Mongo.Collection("Users");

new Tabular.Table({
     name: "Users",
     collection: Users,
     responsive: true,
     autoWidth: true,
     order: [[0, "asc"]],
     columns: [
       {
          data:"profile.firstName",
          title:"First Name",
       },
       {
          data:"profile.lastName",
          title:"Last Name",
       },
       {
          data:"profile.country",
          title:"Country",
       },
       {
          data:"profile.state",
          title:"States",
       },
       {
          data:"profile.createdAt",
          title:"CreatedAt",
          render:function (val) {
              return moment(val).format('DD/MM/YYYY H:mm');
          },
       },
       {
           data:"profile.updatedAt",
           title:"UpdatedAt",
           render:function (val) {
               return moment(val).format('DD/MM/YYYY H:mm');
           },
       },

   ],
    initComplete: function() {
        $('.dataTables_empty').html('processing');
    },
   processing: false

});
```

```
{{> tabular table=TabularTables.Users  class="table table-striped mybooks table-bordered table-condensed"}}
```